# Клики по ячейкам таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

У меня есть 4 ячейки. При клике по ним в каждой появляется "Text 1". Мне нужно, чтобы при клики на ячейку (c1) "кликалась" ячейка (с2). То есть при клике на (с1) одновременно происходил клик на ячейку (с2). Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
<head>
    <script>
        var current = "Text 1";
        function onClick(sender) {
            if (sender.innerText == "") {
                sender.innerHTML = current;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="50px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="c1" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
                <td id="c2" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td id="c3" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
                <td id="c4" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: А при клике на `c2`? А при клике на `c3`? А при клике на `c4`?

Comment: Я бы хотел рассмотреть только один пример, после я сам смогу прописать то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Просто понимаете штука в чем, в зависимости от задачи логика будет разной. например при клике `c1` чтобы происходил еще и клик на `c2` - одно, а если у вас предполагается при клике на `c2` чтоб кликалась `c4` это совсем другое. То есть можно сделать решение на основе миллиона айдишников, что вы присвоите ячейкам, а можно сделать решение на основе общей строки, или общего корня в виде `table`

Comment: Пока мне нужно только при клике с1 происходил еще и клик на c2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var current = "Text 1";

function onClick(sender) {
  if (sender.id == 'c1')
    $('#c2').click();
  
  if (sender.innerText == ""){
    sender.innerHTML = current; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="50px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="c1" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        <td id="c2" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td id="c3" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
        <td id="c4" class="cell" onclick="onClick(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Да, то, что нужно! Спасибо за помощь!